# Not able to send JSON response to other activity and show it in toast

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am able to register json data to my server, I am even getting response, but not able to show it in toast as well as send it to other activity (main activity).

I converted the response to string and tried to send to my mainactivity using getter but I am not able  to see it in `Log.i`, even in toast that I mentioned. Here's my code:

```
class  SendJsonDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String j;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String JsonResponse = "";
        String JsonDATA = params[0];
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://gstedge.com/test/invoice/api.php?param=signup");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            // is output buffer writter
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
//set headers and method
            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(JsonDATA);
// json data
            writer.close();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
//input stream
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
             j= JsonResponse;
//response data
            Log.i("o/p:", JsonResponse);



//send to post execute


            }

         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("wtf", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return JsonResponse;





    }
```

I was not able to get response in onpostexecute as well so I removed it and thought to convert it in string and send it using getter and parse it in other activity. I am able to see response in `log.i("o/p")` mentioned above in the code, but I don't know why its not getting sent.

Here's my mainactivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText emailview, numberview, pwview;
    Button registerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        numberview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        pwview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        registerview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    }

    public void hit(View v) {
        String email = emailview.getText().toString();
        String contact = numberview.getText().toString();
        String pw = pwview.getText().toString();
        JSONObject a = new JSONObject();

        try {
            a.put("mail", email);
            a.put("num", contact);
            a.put("pass", pw);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (a.length() > 0) {
            new SendJsonDataToServer().execute(String.valueOf(a));


        }


        SendJsonDataToServer S = new SendJsonDataToServer();
        String Jr = S.getJR();
        Log.i("out:",Jr);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Jr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserAreaActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

}
}
```

The toast I see is empty.

Comment: Pro posting tips: use a capital letter "I" when referring to yourself, it makes things much easier to read. When discussing code in a paragraph, use `code formatting like this`, which is achieved using backticks. Finally, avoid txtspk, which is often a cause of downvotes - it is not a great effort to type the word "please".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Because you are creating two different objects of `SendJsonDataToServer`

First:

```
new SendJsonDataToServer().execute(String.valueOf(a));
```

Second:

```
SendJsonDataToServer S = new SendJsonDataToServer();
```

So these two objects will get different memory allocation. when you get response by this code

```
String Jr = S.getJR();
```

then you will get the response that was created in different object from the object you got response. So `Jr` will be obviously empty. That's why you cannot print the response that you expect.

**Solution:**

**First:**

You need to execute

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Jr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

method in your `AsyncTask` like this.

**Second:**

If you want to send this result to your second activity then you should write code like this in your `onPostExecute` method.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("result", result);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and write this code in `onCreate()` method of `UserAreaActivity`

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String result = bundle.getString("result");
Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Now you will be able to use result in this activity.

Comment: my friend told me the same thing , and we solved it out , but i am accepting your answer. It is same and correct. Thanks :)